# Check for multiple null isset values

Tags: php, isset

I am checking if two values are `null`. If both are `null` I want to return `false`, if either or both are **not** `null`, I want to return `true`.

My current code returns `true` only when both are not `null` but I want it to return `true` when either or not `null`.

```
// check if both null
   if (!isset($myarray['dataone'], $myarray['datatwo']))
       {
           echo 'false';
        );    
       } else {
           echo 'true';
        );
       }
       return $emptytabs;
```

Comment: use a different method, with `||`'s and possibly `&&` inside a bracketed conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use relational operators. AND (&&) OR (||)

By using AND (&&) operators.

```
if ( (!isset($myarray['dataone']) || (!isset$myarray['datatwo'] ))
{
    echo 'false';  
} 
else 
{
    echo 'true';
}
```

By using OR ( || ) operators.

```
if (isset($myarray['dataone'] && isset$myarray['datatwo'])
{
    echo 'false';  
} 
else 
{
    echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// check if both null
if ( !isset($myarray['dataone']) && !isset($myarray['datatwo']))  {
        echo 'false';
    } else {
        echo 'true';
    }

// check if one or both are null
if ( !isset($myarray['dataone']) || !isset($myarray['datatwo']))  {
        echo 'false';
    } else {
        echo 'true';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// check if both null

if ( !isset($myarray['dataone'], $myarray['datatwo']) )
    {
        echo 'false';

    } else {
       echo 'true';
}
return $emptytabs;
```

this approach you provided is totally true , but it only return true if all the provided parameters are set according to `php` documentations  .

so your code should works correctly . except you have unwanted parentheses that should deleted

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the OR (`||`) operator. You want to show 'true' if one thing is set *OR* another thing is set. Just say that with code.

```
if ( isset($myarray['dataone']) || isset($myarray['datatwo']) ) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Using the AND operator adds pointless complexity by checking that both of the two things are not set in order for it to show 'false'. That's not an intuitive way to think about it, so it doesn't make sense to write the code that way.

<sub>DISCLAIMER: This answer is opinionated.</sub>